# Injecting code from a module/class into another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, metaprogramming, dry

I would like to know the common practice to inject code from a module/class into another module/class. I have:

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # The has_many association for Article / Post.
    has_many :comments

    # Here, from MyModule, I would like to "inject" the related belongs_to 
    # association into Comment where the belongs_to association should be
    # 'belongs_to :article' for Article and 'belongs_to :post' for Post.
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # ...
  end
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

To inject the `belongs_to` association into `Comment`, I can use the `instance_exec` method, but maybe, there is a more smart approach. What should I do in order to avoid repetition in code? Should I `include` other modules in `Comment`, or keep all the related code in `MyModule`, and inject it from there? How to proceed in these cases?

Comment: You cannot include `MyModule` before it is defined. It is misleading/confusing to present a piece of code in the order that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a model belongs to more than one other model you can use [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), and you can use class_eval to include a module:

```
module MyModule  
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern  

  included do  
    has_many :comments, as: postable  

    Comment.class_eval do
      include Commentable
    end
  end 

  Module Commentable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true
    end

    def ping
      p 'pong'
    end
  end 
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule
end


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

In a non-polymorphic way you can define included like this:

```
def self.included(base)
  Comment.class_eval do
    belongs_to base.name.underscore # Will result in belongs_to :article and belongs_to :post in this case
  end
end
```

Comment: I know that I can use polymorphic associations but this is not the case because *there is more* than the `belongs_to` association to share. For example there are other methods to share.

Comment: You set the `belongs_to :postable` association. There is a way to name it when including the module? That is, I would like to have a `belongs_to <custom_name>` which `<custom_name>` changes based on custom options.... maybe, when including the module I can pass some `options` as argument, if possible...

Comment: Yes, but at the end I didn't utilized it. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code like the following to do something similar in one of my projects:

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    ...
  end

  def self.included(other)
    Comment.belongs_to(other.to_s.underscore.to_sym, {:options => 'whatever'})
  end

end
```